# How do I dump output of an external command to a new buffer in Vim?

Tags: vim

`:enew` lets me create a new buffer and `:.!<command>` lets me dump the output of an external command to that buffer.  Can I combine the two into a one liner?

Thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/157987/pipe-output-of-shell-command-into-a-new-buffer-in-vim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'|' is used to chain commands together in vim. so

```
:enew | .! <command>
```

should do what you want

Answer (score 3):

`:.!` actually pipes the current line through the external command, possibly losing the line. You may wish to use `:r !<command>`—Note the space before the `!`. I often use `:0r !cmd` so that the output is inserted at the start of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`:vnew | read !<command>`

Execute the command and place the output in a new vertically split buffer. Use `#` to pass the path of the current buffer to the command. e.g.

`:vnew | read !python -m json.tool #`

> Using python's JSON module to format the working JSON file.

Alternatively, the [AsyncCommand](https://github.com/idbrii/AsyncCommand) plugin can be used to "run any program and load results in a split" buffer asynchronously.

Additional reading:

- `:h new`
- `:h read`