# In terminal - show ouput in new vim buffer

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm trying to get the functionality that I saw in a video. Essentially the person was in the terminal (I believe using tmux in case that matters) and with a shortcut turned stdout into a vim buffer and could easily navigate and select/copy text that way. How is this done?

Comment: On the terminal's side it's a `tmux` feature, read about `copy-mode` in the manual.  On Vim's side it's just paste, but do read `:h 'clipboard'`.  There's also `vipe(1)` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about `tmux`'s copy mode

By default you can get in to copy mode by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> If `C-b` is your prefix. Otherwise use prefix + <kbd>[</kbd>

You can use motion with <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>, search with <kbd>?</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> etc.

Some related [details](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/love-hate-tmux)

Answer (score 0):

`tabnew` command is used to open a new tab.

You can use a pipeline symbol and then other commands. The output of those commands will be redirected to new buffer.

Example:

```
         :tabnew | r! pwd
```

pwd will print the current directory and r will read it. Tabnew will put that output in new buffer.
You can use both shell commands as well as vim commands.

Similarly, `enew` command can be used instead of tabnew for new buffer.
See here:
https://superuser.com/questions/157987/pipe-output-of-shell-command-into-a-new-buffer-in-vim

[How to redirect stdout output to a new Vim tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287164/how-to-redirect-stdout-output-to-a-new-vim-tab)

[How do I dump output of an external command to a new buffer in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826003/how-do-i-dump-output-of-an-external-command-to-a-new-buffer-in-vim)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `:read !<cmd>` to execute a command in shell and capture the output to current buffer.

For example - `:read !date`

If you want the output in a new buffer, use `:new`.

So both combined, `:new | read !date`

Answer (score 0):

In readline, in the default emacs mode, you can press `<C-x><C-e>` to edit the current command line in `$EDITOR`.

If you use vi mode, you can press `<Esc>v` to do the same.